# How to make a modular, nested dropdown menu that can be added to?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, codepen

I'm making a website from scratch and am trying to make a nested dropdown menu system.

But currently, it's very cobbled together and I can't add more menus to it without the entire thing falling apart. Is there some simple methodology to this that I'm missing?

In addition to "Armor, Harnesses, Fields" I want to add "Melee" and "Ranged" who, in turn, have their own submenus.

Here is my code. HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="subnav">
        <button class="subnavbtn">Armor <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="subnav-content">
        <select name="lightArmor" id="lightArmor" onChange="createSelectEAL()">
        <option value=" ">Light Armor(select one)</option>
        <option value="1">Standard-Issue Combat Armour</option>
        <option value="2">Light-Weave Coat</option>
        <option value="3">Skirmisher Suit</option>
        <option value="4">Drakeling-Class Protector</option>
        <option value="5">Spectre Armour</option>
        <option value="6">Quicksilver Nanosuit</option>
        </select>
        <select name="mediumtArmor" id="mediumArmor" onChange="createSelectEAM()">
        <option value=" ">Medium Armor(select one)</option>
        <option value="7">Red Crystal Coat</option>
        <option value="8">Safetree-Core Suit</option>
        <option value="9">Basic Infantry Armour</option>
        <option value="10">GUTS Defender</option>
        <option value="11">Avenger Armour</option>
        <option value="12">Valkyrie Aerial Combat Suit</option>
        </select>
        <select name="heavyArmor" id="heavyArmor" onChange="createSelectEAH()">
        <option value=" ">Heavy Armor(select one)</option>
        <option value="13">Heavy-Duty Ceramic</option>
        <option value="14">Dragon Scale Mail</option>
        <option value="15">PRIDE Armour</option>
        <option value="16">Hao Reborn Exosuit</option>
        <option value="17">INVICTUS</option>
        <option value="18">Garm Infantry-Class Power Armor</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subnav">
        <button class="subnavbtn">Harnesses <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="subnav-content">
        <select name="harness" id="harness" onChange="createSelectEH()">
        <option value=" ">(select one)</option>
        <option value="bareeh">Bare Emitter Harness</option>
        <option value="threadedh">Threaded Harness</option>
        <option value="jacketede">Jacketed Emitter</option>
        <option value="emitterp">Emitter Prototype</option>
        <option value="portablesg">Portable Shield Generator</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subnav">
        <button class="subnavbtn">Fields <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="subnav-content">
        <select name="kineticS" id="kineticS" onChange="createSelectKF()">
        <option value=" ">Kinetic(select one)</option>
        <option value=1>"Vest" Low-Grade Force Field, Slots: 1</option>
        <option value=2>"Kite" Low-Grade Force Field, Slots: 1</option>
        <option value=3>"Warden" Standard-Grade Force Field, Slots: 2</option>
        <option value=4>"Target" Standard-Grade Force Field, Slots: 2</option>
        <option value=5>"Kevlar" Mid-Grade Force Field, Slots: 3</option>
        <option value=6>"Tower" Mid-Grade Force Field, Slots: 3</option>
        <option value=7>"Knight" High-Grade Force Field, Slots: 4</option>
        <option value=8>"Riot" High-Grade Force Field, Slots: 4</option>
        <option value=9>"Concrete" Great-Grade Force Field, Slots: 5</option>
        <option value=10>"Deflector" Great-Grade Force Field, Slots: 5</option>
        <option value=11>"Stonewall" Heavy-Grade Force Field, Slots: 6</option>
        <option value=12>"Aegis" Heavy-Grade Force Field, Slots: 6</option>
        </select>
        <select name="energyS" id="energyS" onChange="createSelectEF()">
        <option value=" ">Energy(select one)</option>
        <option value=1>"Curtain" Light Shield, Slots: 1</option>
        <option value=2>"Buckler" Light Shield, Slots: 1</option>
        <option value=3>"Trooper" Standard Shield, Slots: 2</option>
        <option value=4>"Disc" Standard Shield, Slots: 2</option>
        <option value=5>"Diversion" Medium Shield, Slots: 3</option>
        <option value=6>"Mirror" Medium Shield, Slots: 3</option>
        <option value=7>"Blank" High Shield, Slots: 4</option>
        <option value=8>"Pool" High Shield, Slots: 4</option>
        <option value=9>"Limiter" Great Shield, Slots: 5</option>
        <option value=10>"Sky Catcher" Great Shield, Slots: 5</option>
        <option value=11>"Fractal" Heavy Shield, Slots: 6</option>
        <option value=12>"Blast Barrier" Heavy Shield, Slots: 6</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

```css
 /* The navigation menu */
  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#00008b;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 390px;
  }
  
  /* Navigation links */
  .navbar p {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* The subnavigation menu */
  .subnav {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* Subnav button */
  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* Add a grey background color to navigation links on hover */
  .navbar p:hover, .subnav:hover, .subnavbtn {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */
  .subnav-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* Style the subnav links */
  .subnav-content p {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* Add a grey background color on hover */
  .subnav-content p:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */
  .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
    display: block;
  }
```

```js
//EQUIPMENT
function createSelectEH() {
  var field = document.getElementById("harness");

  if (field.options[field.selectedIndex].text == "Bare Emitter Harness") {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nBare Emitter Harness - Passive(2), 4/4 HP, Heavy(4), Bubble/Directed Slot: 1\n`;
  } else if (field.options[field.selectedIndex].text == "Threaded Harness") {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nThreaded Harness - Passive(2), 4/4 HP, Heavy(8), Bubble/Directed Slot: 2\n`;
  } else if (field.options[field.selectedIndex].text == "Jacketed Emitter") {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nJacketed Emitter - Passive(2), 4/4 HP, Heavy(12), Bubble Slot: 3\n`;
  } else if (field.options[field.selectedIndex].text == "Emitter Prototype") {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nEmitter Prototype - Passive(2), 4/4 HP, Heavy(16), Bubble Slot: 4\n`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nPortable Shield Generator - Passive(2), 4/4 HP, Heavy(20), Bubble Slot: 5\n`;
  }
}

function createSelectEAL() {
  var larmor = document.getElementById("lightArmor");

  if (larmor.options[larmor.selectedIndex].value == 1) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nStandard-Issue Combat Armour:  Passive 4, 10/10 HP, Resist Energy (3)\n`;
  } else if (larmor.options[larmor.selectedIndex].value == 2) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nLight-Weave Coat: Passive 5,  12/12 HP, Resist Energy (3)\n`;
  } else if (larmor.options[larmor.selectedIndex].value == 3) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nSkirmisher Suit: Passive 6, 14/14 HP, Resist Energy (3)\n`;
  } else if (larmor.options[larmor.selectedIndex].value == 4) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nDrakeling-Class Protector: Passive 7, 16/16 HP, Energy Resist (4), Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else if (larmor.options[larmor.selectedIndex].value == 5) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nSpectre Armour: Passive 8, 18/18 HP, Resist Energy (4),  Chameleon (4), Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nQuicksilver Nanosuit: Passive 9, 20/20 HP, Resist Energy (4), Healing (20),  Chameleon (4), Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  }
}

function createSelectEAM() {
  var marmor = document.getElementById("mediumArmor");
  if (marmor.options[marmor.selectedIndex].value == 7) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nRed Crystal Coat : Passive 5, 16 / 16 HP, Resist Energy(3)\n`;
  } else if (marmor.options[marmor.selectedIndex].value == 8) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nSafetree - Core Suit : Passive 7, 17 / 17 HP, Resist Energy(3)\n`;
  } else if (marmor.options[marmor.selectedIndex].value == 9) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nBasic Infantry Armour : Passive 9, 18 / 18 HP, Resist Energy(2), Resist Kinetic(2)\n`;
  } else if (marmor.options[marmor.selectedIndex].value == 10) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nGUTS Defender : Passive 10, 20 / 20 HP, Resist Energy(3), Resist Kinetic(3), Heavy(4), Vacuum - Sealed\n`;
  } else if (marmor.options[marmor.selectedIndex].value == 11) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nAvenger Armour : Passive 10, 22 / 22 HP, Resist Energy(3), Resist Kinetic(3), Heavy(4), Plating, Vacuum - Sealed\n`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nValkyrie Aerial Combat Suit : Passive 10, 24 / 24, Winged(4), Resist Energy(3), Resist Kinetic(3), Heavy(4), Plating, Vacuum - Sealed\n`;
  }
}

function createSelectEAH() {
  var harmor = document.getElementById("heavyArmor");
  if (harmor.options[harmor.selectedIndex].value == 13) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nHeavy-Duty Ceramic: Passive 7, 10/10 HP, Resist Kinetic (5), Heavy (4), Plated, Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else if (harmor.options[harmor.selectedIndex].value == 14) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nDragon Scale Mail: Passive 9, 15/15 HP, Resist Kinetic (5), Heavy (6), Plated, Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else if (harmor.options[harmor.selectedIndex].value == 15) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nPRIDE Armour: Passive 11, 20/20 HP, Resist Kinetic (5), Heavy (8), Strength-Boost (3), Plated, Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else if (harmor.options[harmor.selectedIndex].value == 16) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nHao Reborn Exosuit: Passive 13, 25/25 HP, Resist Kinetic (5), Heavy (10), Strength-Boost (6), Plated, Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else if (harmor.options[harmor.selectedIndex].value == 17) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nINVICTUS: Passive 15, 30/30 HP, Resist Kinetic (5), Heavy (10), Strength-Boost (6), Plated, Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\nGarm Infantry-Class Power Armor: Passive 17, 40/40, Resist Kinetic (5), Heavy(12), Plated, Strength-Boost(6), Vacuum-Sealed\n`;
  }
}

function createSelectKF() {
  var kfield = document.getElementById("kineticS");
  if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 1) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Vest" Low-Grade Force Field - 10/10 KHP, Regeneration(10), Kinetic Resistance(5), Bubble, Slots: 1\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 2) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Kite" Low-Grade Force Field - 14/14 KHP, Regeneration(14), Kinetic Resistance(7), Directed(Arm), Slots: 1`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 3) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Warden" Standard-Grade Force Field - 14/14 KHP, Regeneration(26), Kinetic Resistance(5), Bubble, Slots: 2
\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 4) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Target" Standard-Grade Force Field - 19/19 KHP, Regeneration(35), Kinetic Resistance(8), Directed(Arm), Slots: 2
\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 5) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Kevlar" Mid-Grade Force Field - 18/18 KHP, Regeneration(42), Kinetic Resistance(6), Bubble, Slots: 3
\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 6) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Tower" Mid-Grade Force Field - 24/24 KHP, Regeneration(56), Kinetic Resistance(8), Directed(Arm), Slots: 3
\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 7) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Knight" High-Grade Force Field - 22/22 KHP, Regeneration(58), Kinetic Resistance(7), Bubble, Slots: 4\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 8) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Riot" High-Grade Force Field - 29/29 KHP, Regeneration(77), Kinetic Resistance(8), Directed(Arm), Slots: 4\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 9) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Concrete" Great-Grade Force Field - 26/26 KHP, Regeneration(74), Kinetic Resistance(8), Bubble, Slots: 5\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 10) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Deflector" Great-Grade Force Field - 35/35 KHP, Regeneration(98), Kinetic Resistance(9), Directed(Arm), Slots: 5\n`;
  } else if (kfield.options[kfield.selectedIndex].value == 11) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Stonewall" Heavy-Grade Force Field - 30/30 KHP, Regeneration(90), Kinetic Resistance(8), Bubble, Slots: 6\n`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Aegis" Heavy-Grade Force Field - 40/40 KHP, Regeneration(120), Kinetic Resistance(10), Directed(Arm), Slots: 6\n`;
  }
}

function createSelectEF() {
  var efield = document.getElementById("energyS");
  if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 1) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Curtain" Light Shield - 12/12 EHP, Regeneration(12), Energy Resistance(6), Bubble, Slots: 1\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 2) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Buckler" Light Shield - 16/16 EHP, Regeneration(16), Energy Resistance(8), Directed(Arm), Slots: 1`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 3) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Trooper" Standard Shield - 19/19 EHP, Regeneration(29), Energy Resistance(8), Bubble, Slots: 2\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 4) {
    document.querySelector(".equipment").innerHTML += `\n"Disc" Standard Shield
- 24/24 EHP, Regeneration(36) Energy Resistance(10), Directed(Arm), Slots: 2\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 5) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Diversion" Medium Shield - 26/26 EHP, Regeneration(46), Energy Resistance(10), Bubble, Slots: 3\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 6) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Mirror" Medium Shield - 32/32 EHP, Regeneration(56), Energy Resistance(12), Directed(Arm), Slots: 3\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 7) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Blank" High Shield - 33/33 EHP, Regeneration(63), Energy Resistance(10), Bubble, Slots: 4\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 8) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Pool" High Shield- 40/40 EHP, Regeneration(76), Energy Resistance(14), Directed(Arm), Slots: 4\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 9) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Limiter" Great Shield - 40/40 EHP, Regeneration(80), Energy Resistance(12), Bubble, Slots: 5\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 10) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Sky Catcher" Great Shield - 60/60 EHP, Regeneration(100), Energy Resistance(15), Directed(Arm), Slots: 5\n`;
  } else if (efield.options[efield.selectedIndex].value == 11) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Fractal" Heavy Shield - 50/50 EHP, Regeneration(80), Energy Resistance(12), Bubble, Slots: 6\n`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      ".equipment"
    ).innerHTML += `\n"Blast Barrier" Heavy Shield - 70/70 EHP, Regeneration(120), Energy Resistance(15), Directed(Arm), Slots: 6\n`;
  }
}
```